# e.preventDefault() not working from js file of Flask App

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I am having an issue with my jQuery event-listener not working for a form of my Flask app. The page is still refreshing upon the form submission despite the use of the preventDefault() function. Any insight as the why this is happening?

app.js:

```
$("#submit-word").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('testing')
})
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1 id="title">Boggle</h1>
<div class="game-div">
    <table id="game-board">
        {% for row in session['board'] %}
            <tr>
                {% for letter in row %}
                    <td>{{letter}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <form action="" id="submit-word">
        <label for="word-guess">Submit Words:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="word" id="word-guess">
        <button id="submit-me">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the function actually getting called?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be as the page just refreshes with the form submission

Comment: Just wrap JQuery in $(function() {} see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Since you are using a template... Is that `content block` repeating multiple times? Any loop used? An `id` must be unique...

Comment: View the page source once you have it in the browser, and check that it's what you expect. Also open up the browsers developer tools to see check for syntax errors in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...no errors raised from the javascript. The file is running through the app as I checked with a simple alert but I'm still having trouble with the event-listener for the form submission still refreshing the page